# Create a file in 700 (drwx------) directory using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci-runner, alpine-linux

I am using the gitlab-runner base image for my docker file

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
WORKDIR /app

RUN touch /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml   # it doesn't work because of drwx------ direcotry
RUN touch /etc/config.toml                 # it worked because etc is   drwxr-xr-x directory 

COPY . /app
...
...

ENTRYPOINT ["yarn"]
CMD ["run", "start"]
```

Inspecting the images using a tool

[image: permissions]

When the image is created I couldn't see the config.toml file in the `etc/gitlab-runner directory`

1. Is it hidden?
2. How can I create config.toml file under etc/gitlab-runner directory

Also, wondering what purpose of the certs folder? what does it contain? Actually I wanted to mount the config.toml file to the host machine so that the runner details are syn always when the container is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

> Actually I wanted to mount the config.toml file to the host machine so that the runner details are syn always when the container is destroyed.

From this statement, I guess you no need to worry about creating a file as your intention is to mount the file from the host to the container. 
On a Linux environment (on your host machine). 
create a folder in your app folder and file in it as:

```sh
mkdir config
touch config.toml
```

Now update your docker file as:

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
...
...

ENTRYPOINT ["yarn"]
CMD ["run", "start"]
```

Now you rebuild your image and start your container as:

```
docker build -t username/image_name .
docker run -v "absolute path to the folder config":"/etc/gitlab-runner/" username/image_name
```

Now you should see `config.toml` file mounted to the /etc/gitlab-runner and also container runs with no errors.

Comment: Please let me know if any changes required or any of your other concerns here.

Comment: thanks Mehant Kammakomati, i was able to mount and run the container but when i execute gitlab runner register command from from container it show me 509 certificate signed by unknow error, any idea on this ? also is it like the config.toml file is not present in container.

Comment: Please feel free to look at this thread https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3490

Answer (score 1):

The `gitlab/gitlab-runner` image [declares a `VOLUME` for `/etc/gitlab-runner`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/gitlab/gitlab-runner/latest/images/sha256-31fd1cf51007bb4ccd20222a5ca85ccd5468ac85ec83304454fc655fdb9823c3?context=explore), so any `RUN` commands that affect that directory are ignored.

You don't need any Dockerfile changes to inject things like config files using `docker run -v` options (the file doesn't need to already exist in the base image and you don't need a `VOLUME` directive).  You can use any location in the container as the target for a bind mount.  If it's a file, it must exist on the host first, and at startup time the host content will always hide whatever was in the image.

Comment: Hi @David Maze, as per the base link the volume is already mapped (host machine directory is exact - /etc/gitlab-runner which has both config.toml file and certs) but when I run the container without -v, it error with msg config.toml could not be found. docker run -v seems to work as i am able to read the records. But certs is not getting mount that why i believe getting 509 error while writing it to a file. Any idea how i can verify the mount is properly made between host and docker container.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention any bind mounts or `docker run` options at all; it focuses on the `RUN touch` command and the file not being present.  If you're having a problem with GitLab setup, you might ask a separate question that focuses on that.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, totally agreed with you. Sorry for changing the context. Coming back.. why RUN commands is ignored if VOLUME is declare in base image, I am newbie here.. having trouble understanding it. Can you please help me out with it. Thanks

Comment: At a technical level, because each `RUN` command runs in a new container, the `VOLUME` directive causes an anonymous volume to be mounted into that container, and the resulting implicit commit ignores volumes.  This is the same reason you mostly can't create a database image with preloaded data.